# Why is my List data null after my android app is destroyed?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

After my app is destroyed, when I click an item in my listview, it's supposed to copy the data to the clipboard instead the data is returned null although I do infact count some items in the list.

**Here's some code:**

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayList("list", listFragment.getLocations());
}
```

---

```
public void populateList(final StorageManager topItem,
                         final StorageManager bottomItem) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            locations = topItem.readFile();
            times = bottomItem.readFile();
            for (int index = 0; index < locations.size() && index < times.size(); index++) {
                Map<String, UserLocation> data = new HashMap<String, UserLocation>();
                data.put("Top", new UserLocation(index, locations.get(index)));
                data.put("Bottom", new UserLocation(index, times.get(index)));
                list.add(data);
            }
            Collections.reverse(list);
            Collections.reverse(locations);
        }
    });
    thread.run();
}
```

---

```
    @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String dataToSend = TwoItemListFragment.locations.get(position);

    if (null != mListener) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(TwoItemListFragment.list.get(position).hashCode());
    }
    try {
        copyData(dataToSend);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, dataToSend + "");
    }
}
```

---

```
     */
public void copyData(String data) {
    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    String copied = getString(R.string.copied);
    Toast copyToast = Toast.makeText(context, copied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    try {
        cl.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("copy", data));
        copyToast.show();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not copy data: NullPointerException");
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(TwoItemListFragment.locations.size()));
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(TwoItemListFragment.locations.get(1)));
        copyToast = Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.null_text), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        copyToast.show();
    }
}
```

**Some Logcat data**

```
07-25 02:30:42.172  13968-13968/com.DXC0.locationmanagertests.app E/com.DXC0.locationmanagertests.app.TwoItemListFragment﹕ Could not copy data: NullPointerException
07-25 02:30:42.172  13968-13968/com.DXC0.locationmanagertests.app D/com.DXC0.locationmanagertests.app.TwoItemListFragment﹕ 5
```

---

**EDIT:**
Just checked, the data I'm sending is NOT null, it does in fact exist; but for some reason, it returns null still. The problem seems to be this line

```
            cl.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("copy", data));
```

Comment: If the app has been destroyed (do you mean your activity?), your data will not be available.

Comment: Yes, after the GC destroys it. I do try to retrieve the data when I save it in onSaveInstanceState and have tried to retrieve it, but it's still null--as you can see in the log data.

Comment: The data is not null, it has something to do with trying to copy the data to the user's clipboard.

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer below.

Comment: I will do in the morning... I have less than 10 rep since I don't come here much.

Comment: @user3398918 - That sounds like a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: @StephenC pretty much. Wasn't immediately clear which was null and I wrongly assumed it was the list data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ClipboardManager "cl" was null for some reason, so in my try block, I reinitialised and it worked. The data was never null.

```
    try {
        cl = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).clipboardManager();
        cl.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("copy", data));
        copyToast.show();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not copy data: NullPointerException");
        copyToast = Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.null_text), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        copyToast.show();
    }
```